# Menu button not visible on MasterDetailPage after removing previous page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The main page of the app is set to a `NavigationPage`.

I have a common scenario where I have a login page (`ContentPage`) and then I navigate to app's main page (`MasterDetailPage`).

The code I run on login page is something like this:

```
var mainPage = new MasterDetailTestPage();
await this.Navigation.PushAsync(mainPage);
this.Navigation.RemovePage(this); // remove login page
```

The issue is the menu button is not visible on the `MasterDetailPage`.

If instead of this I set the main page to `MasterDetailPage` on app start like this:

`MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MasterDetailTestPage());`

in this case the menu button is shown. But this only works if it's set at the beginning. It doesn't work if app starts with login page and then setting `MainPage`.

It looks like the `MasterDetailTestPage` doesn't display menu button unless it's the root page of `NavigationPage`.

I reproduced this on a sample app too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **MasterDetailPage** with button will only appear if it sets in root page a `NavigationPage`. In your case you shoud do something like this.

  public partial class App : Application
  {

  ```
  public App()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage());
  }
  ```
- The `MenuPage` Contains the MasterDetailPage with a `List`, and then when navigates to another page(`LoginPage`) you can do your logic and then :

  ```
  public async void login_clicked(object sender ,EventArgs e)
  {
     //.....your logic
      await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
  }
  ```
- So now you can return and navigate to your `MasterDetailPage` with a visible button, because it removes all pages that was in stack. I hope it helps you.